# SpringBoot JSON not deserializing into my request model

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using SpringBoot and trying to deserialize JSON like:

```
{
  "userId": "Dave",
  "queryResults": {
    "id": "ABC",
    "carData": {.....},
    "carId": "Honda",
    "status": 0,
    "model": "X"
  }
}
```

, into `MyRequestModel` clas:

```
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private String: queryResults;
}
```

, that is received as `@RequestBody` parameter in my `@PostMapping` method that looks like:

```
    @PostMapping
    public String postDate(@RequestBody MyRequestModel data) {
        ...
        
        return "posted";
    }
```

The above `queryResults` field is supposed to be stored as a CLOB in a database.

Problem I am having is that if I send this JSON to hit my endpoint (PostMapping) method, it cannot deserialize it into `MyRequestModel` and I get this error:

**Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 18] (through reference chain: MyRequestModel["queryResults"])]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the real answer to your question is: if you NEED the `queryResults` property to be a `String`, then implement a custom deserializer.

If not, then, use one of the alternatives that Jonatan and Montaser proposed in the other answers.

Implementing a custom deserializer within Spring Boot is fairly straightforward, since Jackson is its default serializer / deserializer and it provides a easy way to write our own deserializer.

First, create a class that implements the `StdDeserializer<T>`:

**MyRequestModelDeserializer.java**

```java
public class MyRequestModelDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyRequestModel> {

    public MyRequestModelDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MyRequestModelDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public MyRequestModel deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

        String userId = node.get("userId").asText();
        String queryResults = node.get("queryResults").toString();

        MyRequestModel model = new MyRequestModel();
        model.setQueryResults(queryResults);
        model.setUserId(userId);

        return model;
    }

}
```

Second, mark your class to be deserialized using your custom deserializer by using the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation:

**MyRequestModel.java**

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyRequestModelDeserializer.class)
public class MyRequestModel {
    private String userId;
    private String queryResults;
}
```

It's done.

Comment: Thank you.  That looks exactly what I need however the json object for `queryResults` is retrieved as empty string for some reason.  Any idea why would above line reading `queryResults` from JSON node return empty string?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Could you, please, show me your code so I can see if there's something wrong with your implementation?

Comment: Could you elaborate the 2 constructors above?  I read few articles but non explain the meaning what they do and why they are needed.  Especially the one with `this(null)` call?  Also, I changed `.asText()` to `.toString()` and am just about to retest to see if that will work.

Comment: . . . My mistake, answer edited. Use `toString()` on `node.get("queryResults")` to retrieve the JSON. `asText()` doesn't work for object type fields of JSON. . . Now, for your question, the default constructor with `this(null)` is used by Jackson's `ObjectMapper` when creating the deserializer instance. . . The other constructor - `MyRequestModelDeserializer(Class<?> vc)` - you can even omit it and do just `public MyRequestModelDeserializer(){this(MyRequestModel.class);}`. This constructor is used to set the handled class to the `StdDeserializer` so you can access the handled type at Runtime.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am using `this(MyRequestModel.class)` instead and using `.asText()` for userId (as that does not add 2 additional characters which are the quotation marks around userId so my DB field length does not become to short) and `.toString()` to get the `queryResults` CLOB string value.  Much appreciated Matheus~

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to deserialize this request:-

1. change the type of `queryResults` to `Map<String, Object>`, it will accepts everything as an object of `key` and `value`. (Not recommended)

```java
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private Map<String, Object> queryResults;
}
```

2. You have to create a class that wraps the results of `queryResults` as an object.

```java
class QueryResult {

    private String id;

    private Map<String, Object> carData;

    private String carId;

    private Integer status;

    private String model;

    public QueryResult() {}

    public QueryResult(String id, Map<String, Object> carData, String carId, Integer status, String model) {
        this.id = id;
        this.carData = carData;
        this.carId = carId;
        this.status = status;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCarData() {
        return carData;
    }

    public void setCarData(Map<String, Object> carData) {
        this.carData = carData;
    }

    public String getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(String carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

and make the type of `queryResult` as shown:-

```java
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private QueryResult queryResults;
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated Montaser.  For now, I will have to stick with String as that is the requirement but that might change.  So, for now I have to store it into DB as CLOB so it has to be string.

Answer (score 1):

`queryResults` is a `String` on Java side but it is an `Object` on JSON side.
You will be able to deserialize it if you send it in as a `String`:

```json
{
  "userId": "Dave",
  "queryResults": "foo"
}
```

or if you create classes that maps to the fields:

```java
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private QueryResults queryResults;
}

public class QueryResults {
   private String id;
   private CarData carData;
   private String carId;
   private Integer status;
   private String model;
}
```

or if you serialize it into something generic (not recommended):

```java
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private Object queryResults;
}
```

```java
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private Map<String, Object> queryResults;
}
```

```java
public class MyRequestModel {
   private String userId;
   private JsonNode queryResults;
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated Jonatan.  I think I might consider doing that in next iteration but right now, the requirement is to use CLOB to store that value into DB as CLOB.

Comment: As far as I remember, you will get what you need if you call `toString()` on the `JsonNode` (see my last example). In that case, you don't need a custom logic to deserialize the request, it will be a little more readable and flexible.

Just do `String.valueOf(request.getQueryResults())` when you create the object that you push to the DB.